# Created android directory but not visible via PC usb connection

Tags: android, file-io, android-external-storage

My code creates a .csv file in a specific directory that I want to be visible by a PC when I access the phones storage with a USB cable.

```
private final String SPECTRA_CSV_DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Spectra_Logs";

 public void saveMeasurementToFiles(String[] data) { //ADHI 1.4.4

    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        if (directoryExists(SPECTRA_CSV_DIRECTORY)) {
            try {
                File spectraLog = new File(createCSVFileName(0));
                spectraLog.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(spectraLog, true);

                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    fos.write((data[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes());

                fos.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                messageLogger.saveErrorToFile(SmartUtilities.getStackTrace(e), "CSV_Save_Error");
                Toast.makeText(this, "CSV Save: Error accessing file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                messageLogger.saveErrorToFile(SmartUtilities.getStackTrace(e), "CSV_Save_Error");
                Toast.makeText(this, "CSV Save: Error with data stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                messageLogger.saveErrorToFile(SmartUtilities.getStackTrace(e), "CSV_Save_Error");
                Toast.makeText(this, "CSV Save: Unknown error occurred, check error logs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are some of the code for the methods that are called so you have an idea of what the code is doing.

```
private boolean directoryExists(String path) {
    try {
        File folder = new File(path);
        boolean exists = folder.exists();

        // Check if exists, if not; create it
        if (!exists)
            exists = folder.mkdirs();

        // Check if successful
        if (exists) {
            Log.d("FILE IO:", "Spectra directory found or created successfully");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Log.d("FILE IO ERROR:", "Spectra directory missing - cannot be resolved.");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Spectra directory missing - cannot be resolved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("FILE IO ERROR:", "Problem saving spectra csv to storage");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving spectra csv to storage.\n\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have rooted my phone and I can use root browser to view the directory where it should be (I assume) and open the .csv files with a text editior. The directory path is as follows:

> storage/emulated/0/Spectra_Logs

... but when I plug my phone into the computer I cannot see any of the .csv files, which is disappointing because all I wanted to use these files for was exportation onto my computer.

So my first question is: Why are they not visible to the PC?

Second question: How do I make them visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution the problem for anyone encountering the same thing.

- unplug phone from computer
- go to --- settings > apps > app info
- use the options to show system apps
- settings > apps > app info (system apps) > external storage > app data > storage
- then press clear data
- go to --- settings > apps > app info
- use the options to show system apps
- settings > apps > app info (system apps) > media storage > app data > storage
- then press clear data
- restart the phone
- plug the phone back into the pc
- set the phone to transfer files (mtp)
- updated/new folders should be visible

I'm not sure why the phone requires you to do this or if there's a way to refresh this programatically when the files are created but if I discover any further information I'll post it in a comment below this answer.